# sorting messages in order based on top scores input by the user

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, java.util.scanner

I have these 4 sentences that are printed and basically want the user to input a score for each sentence out of 10 and store them in array and then include a way of sorting the sentences in order of the scores given to them and print them in the order of highest to lowest

I am new to java, and I am struggling how to go about this problem, I managed to write some code below and thats the furthest ive got. I don't know how to store those printed messages in the array. And i'm not sure how to link the scores with the messages that gets printed.  Can someone help, :/

```
public static void arrays()
    {

        String []noun = {"face", "eyes", "nose", "lips", "ears", "cheeks"}; //stores all the arrays for noun words
        Random random = new Random();  //to work out the new random
        int rand1 = random.nextInt(noun.length); 


        String []verb = {"enchant", "dazzle", "captivate" , "lure", "desire", "entice" }; // stores all the arrays for verb words
        Random random2 = new Random();
        int rand2 = random2.nextInt(verb.length);


        String []adjective = { "alluring", "angelic", "adoring", "appealing", "attractive", "beautiful"}; // stores all the arrays for adjectives
        Random random3 = new Random();
        int rand3 = random3.nextInt(adjective.length);

        printmessage (noun[rand1], verb[rand2], adjective[rand3]);  //to print the message that will use the arguments from the random selected words.

        getscore ();

    }

     public static void printmessage(String noun, String verb, String adjective)  //calls the arguments defined above, which will be used below, when executing the messages.
    {

        System.out.println("line 1: I would love to " + verb + " your " + adjective + " " + noun + "\n");

        System.out.println("line 2: Your are my " + adjective+ " " + noun + " .You " + verb +  " me" + "\n");

        System.out.println("line 3: you always look great in that " + adjective + " dress" + " and you " + verb +  " me with your " + noun + "\n");

        System.out.println("line 4: I get butterflies when I see your " + noun + " , you make me want to " + verb + " , in your " + adjective + " world" + "\n");
    }

    public static void getscore()
    {   
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i=0; i<=3; i++)
        {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the scores for line: " + i);
        int result = input.nextInt();
        int[] scores = new int[result];
        scores[i] = input.nextInt();
        } 

    }
```

Comment: You should read on "variable scope"

Comment: You can keep using `random` where you're using `random2` and `random3`.  In fact, it will be more random if you keep using the same generator.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the call of getScore and print statement as you need score before to print the message. So you could return int array with getScore back to main method like:

```
public static int[] getscore() {
    int[] scores = new int[3];
    //your logic to populate scores 
    return scores;
}
```

Then in your main you use:

```
int count = 0;
int scores [] = getscore ();
Arrays.sort(scores);
printmessage (noun[rand1], verb[rand2], adjective[rand3], score[count++]);  //to print the message that will use the arguments from the random selected words.
```

And in your print message you could use if like below:

```
switch(score) {
    case 1://blah blah 
    break;
    //and so on
}
```